# Add a new column to Table with exisiting primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to add a new column(field) to a table with 4 columns and an extra id column.
But there seems to be a primary key restriction?
can someone help with this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1]( [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, [a] [int] NOT NULL, [b] 
[int] NOT NULL, [c] [int] NOT NULL, [d] [int] NOT NULL, [SCD_Date] [date] NOT NULL, [EndDate] 
[date] NULL, CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: If you try to add a new not nullable column to an exsiting table which already contains data you have to provide a default value for the new column. Otherwise adding won't work.

Comment: A table can have only one primary key, but any number of foreign keys. You can use ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name INTEGER;

Comment: What's the `ALTER TABLE` you're trying to execute and what's the error you get?

Comment: so that's the current table sturcture. I will be adding a column which will have values, error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Again....what is the script you are trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Primary Key in the constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1]( 
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[a] [int] NOT NULL,
[b] [int] NOT NULL,
[c] [int] NOT NULL,
[d] [int] NOT NULL,
[SCD_Date] [date] NOT NULL, 
[EndDate] 
[date] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id asc)
)
```

Comment: @schlonzo the default value varies, depending on the existing table's id. so i have the values for each of the ids